# js array push results returns only length of iterations [moment js & angular]

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, momentjs

I have a function that iterates days in a month. From there i'am displaying them in in my html with ngFor. I wanted to display the day digit as the text and the day name (mon, tue, wed, etc) as the class for each day.

```
monthDays = []; // global variable

  getDaysInMonth(month, year) {
    var date = new Date(year, month);
    var days = []; // 1,2,3
    var daysName = []; // mon, tue, wed
    while (date.getMonth() === month) {
      this.monthDays.push({
        days: days.push(moment(date).format("D")),
        daysName: daysName.push(moment(date).format("M"))
      })
      date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
    }
    console.log(this.monthDays);
  }
```

since i need both attributes (days and daysName) i push them inside a monthDays global variable array but the results are just numbers of the month

```
Array(31) // I.e Jan getDaysInMonth(1,2019)
0: {days: 1, daysName: 1} // should be days: 1 , daysName: 'Tue'
1: {days: 2, daysName: 2} // should be days: 2 , daysName: 'Wed'
```

so i could use the object like so in my html

```
<p *ngFor="let x of monthDays" class="{{x.daysName}}" >{{ x.days }}</p>
```

Any help or push in the right direction would be great.

Comment: Best to check the docs before asking why methods aren't working as you expect - `push` returns the new length of the array, not the mutated array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `push` returns the new length of the array [Array push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push), `days` and `daysName` is length of the array. I think you want get array object with 2 attributes is day and dayname. Try it:

```
monthDays = []; // global variable

getDaysInMonth(month, year) {
    var date = new Date(year, month);
    var days = []; // 1,2,3
    var daysName = []; // mon, tue, wed
    while (date.getMonth() === month) {
        this.monthDays.push({
            days: moment(date).format("D"),
            daysName: moment(date).format("dddd")
        })
        date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
    }
    console.log(this.monthDays);
}
```

Comment: thank you! I saw my issue, i know push returned the length but couldn't understand why, i kept trying to assign the days and daysName within the object to the local variables instead if setting them as properties.